# Can't access Content-Length header in Firefox for Cross-Origin resource

Tags: javascript, http, http-headers, content-length

I'm trying to display the file size of a S3 hosted file. I access it by fetching it with the HEAD method and expect to get access to the Content-Length header, but I don't on Firefox, Edge, or IE. When i open the Browser network tools, I can see all the headers. But if I were to loop through all the headers I have access to in Javascript, I only see content-type and last-modified. When I access content-type, it says it is null.

I've tried changing from content-type to Content-Type, no change.

```
let res = await fetch('my-url', {
   method: 'HEAD'
});

if (res.ok) {
   console.log(res.headers.get('content-length'))
}
```

In Chromium browsers like Chrome, Opera, and Brave it logs the value of the header, but in Firefox, etc.. it logs null.

```
res.headers.forEach((value, key) => {
   console.log(key, value);
})

// Logs in Firefox:
// content-type application/zip
// last-modified Tue, 10 Sep 2019 23:38:07 GMT
```

And when I forEach the headers I only have access to 2 of them in Firefox, while in Chrome I have access to 3.

Comment: You could try adding the content length header to the allowed headers list.

Comment: @Ferrybig Yea that's what I was reading online. I'm gonna try that on Monday and see if it works.